# How can I cut large csv files using any R packages like ff or data.table?

Tags: r, large-data

I want to cut large csv files (file size more than RAM size) and use them or save each in disk for later usage. Which R package is best for doing this for large files?

Comment: If your data is too large to fit in your RAM, data.table is not an option as it needs data to fit into RAM. In which case using ff is a good alternative as it does not require to fit your data in RAM. What have you tried already?

Comment: if have tried ff, bigmemory and sqlite, all failed with 12 GB on 16 GB (+16 GB swap) RAM machine. By failed I mean, R session got terminated

Comment: If you want reasonable help, you should provide a reproducible example to see where you got stuck

Comment: actually these packages failed to even read the large file. So I got stuck right there. As far as I remember, I used read.ffdf of ff package, fread of data.table . FYI: I originally posted this question on stats.stackexchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should have used read.csv.ffdf of ff package with specific parameters like this to read big file:

```
library(ff)
a <- read.csv.ffdf(file="big.csv", header=TRUE, VERBOSE=TRUE, first.rows=1000000, next.rows=1000000, colClasses=NA)
```

Once big file is read into a ff object, Subsetting ffobject into data frames can be done using:
    a[1000:1000000,]

Rest of the code for subsetting and saving broken dataframes
    totalrows = dim(a)[1]
    row.size = as.integer(object.size(a[1:10000,])) / 10000   #in bytes

```
block.size = 200000000  #in bytes .IN Mbs 200 Mb

#rows.block is rows per block
rows.block = ceiling(block.size/row.size)

#nmaps is the number of chunks/maps of big dataframe(ff), nmaps = number of maps - 1
nmaps = floor(totalrows/rows.block)


for(i in (0:nmaps)){
  if(i==nmaps){
    df = a[(i*rows.block+1) : totalrows,]
  }
  else{
    df = a[(i*rows.block+1) : ((i+1)*rows.block),]
  }
  #process df or save it
  write.csv(df,paste0("M",i+1,".csv"))
  #remove df
  rm(df)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried but using `skip` and `nrows` parameters in `read.table` or `read.csv` is worth a try. These are from `?read.table`

> **skip**   integer: the number of lines of the data file to skip before
>   beginning to read data.
>
> **nrows**  integer: the maximum number of rows to read in. Negative and
>   other invalid values are ignored.

To avoid some troublesome issues at the end you need to do some error handling. In other words I don't know what happpens when skip value is greater than the number of rows in your big csv.

p.s. I also don't know whether `header=TRUE` is affecting skip or not, you also have to check that.

Comment: it worked fine if skip was less. but if skip is large (i.e closer towards the end of file) read.csv failed. So evidently R read.csv reads the whole file even if skip is large. 

In my case, it was 123 million rows of 12 GB data, so     
this failed

    """read.csv("big.csv", skip=123660900,nrows=90)"""

failed

Answer (score 3):

The answer given bu @berkorbay is OK and I can confirm that **header** can be used with **skip**. However, if your file is really large it gets painfully slow, as each subsequent reading after the first must skip over all previously read lines.

I had to do something similar and, after wasting quite a bit of time, I wrote a short script in PERL which fragments the original file in chuncks that you can read one after the other. It is **much** faster. I enclose the source here, translating some parts so that the intent is clear:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
system("cls");
print("Fragment .csv file keeping header in each chunk\n") ;

print("\nEnter input file name  = ") ;
$entrada = <STDIN> ;
print("\nEnter maximum number of lines in each fragment = ") ;
$nlineas = <STDIN> ;
print("\nEnter output file name stem   = ") ;
$salida = <STDIN> ;
chop($salida) ;
open(IN,$entrada)    || die "Cannot open input file: $!\n" ;

$cabecera  = <IN> ;
$leidas    = 0  ;
$fragmento = 1  ;
$fichero   = $salida.$fragmento ;
open(OUT,">$fichero") || die "Cannot open output file: $!\n" ;
print OUT $cabecera ;
while(<IN>) {
    if ($leidas > $nlineas) {
    close(OUT) ;
    $fragmento++ ;
    $fichero   = $salida.$fragmento ;
    open(OUT,">$fichero") || die "Cannot open output file: $!\n" ;
    print OUT $cabecera ;
    $leidas = 0;
    }
    $leidas++ ;
    print OUT $_ ;
}
close(OUT) ;
```

Just save with whatever name and execute. The first line might have to be changed if you have PERL in a diferent place (an, if you are on Windows, you migh have to invoke the script as "perl name-of-script").

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can first read the files into mysql using dbWriteTable and then use read.dbi.ffdf function from the ETLUtils package to read it back to R. Consider the function below;

```html
read.csv.sql.ffdf <- function(file, name,overwrite = TRUE, header = TRUE, drv = MySQL(), dbname = "new", username = "root",host='localhost', password = "1234"){
  conn = dbConnect(drv, user = username, password = password, host = host, dbname = dbname)
  dbWriteTable(conn, name, file, header = header, overwrite = overwrite)
  on.exit(dbRemoveTable(conn, name))
  command = paste0("select * from ", name)
  ret = read.dbi.ffdf(command, dbConnect.args = list(drv =drv, dbname = dbname, username = username, password = password))
  return(ret)
}
```